# ASP.net Gridview not sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a gridview that I'd like to sort. I've read a few tutorials and copied most of my code directly from the MSDN page, but I can't get it to work. It compiles, but nothing happens when I click the grid column headers.

My HTML:

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" id="dgrMainGrid" CssClass="c_mainGrid" 
AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowSorting="true" 
OnSorting="TaskGridView_Sorting" />
```

My Codebehind:

```
protected void TaskGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieve the table from the session object.
    DataTable dt = Session["Grid"] as DataTable;

    if (dt != null)
    {
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
        dgrMainGrid.DataSource = dt;
        dgrMainGrid.DataBind();
    }
}

private string GetSortDirection(string column)
{
    // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
    string sortDirection = "ASC";

    // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
    string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

    if (sortExpression != null)
    {
        // Check if the same column is being sorted.
        // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
        if (sortExpression == column)
        {
            string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
            if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
            {
                sortDirection = "DESC";
            }
        }   
    }
    return sortDirection;
}
```

I know the data table in my session variable works, because it's the source for my grid on page load, which works fine. One other thing, if it's important, this gridview resides in an update panel.

As I said, most of this is copied from the MSDN page, and I've been through it until I'm going code-blind. Can someone see my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: what value do you have on AutoPostBack property?

Comment: I didn't have anything, but I just tried both true and false, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `DataGrid`, not a `GridView`. According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx), DataGrid does not have a `OnSorting` event, but an `OnSortCommand`. Either use that or switch to GridView (recommended)

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" OnSortCommand="dgrMainGrid_SortCommand" id="dgrMainGrid" CssClass="c_mainGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowSorting="true" />
```

And in code behind

```
protected void dgrMainGrid_SortCommand(object source, DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = Session["Grid"] as DataTable;

    if (dt != null)
    {
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
        dgrMainGrid.DataSource = dt;
        dgrMainGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And your `GetSortDirection` does not work as it should. See [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: VDWWD, I stared at that for an hour without seeing the problem with my web element (I'd been trying them both while troubleshooting). Thank you so much. I'm psychically buying you a beer right now.